# How to read the kernel panic report?

Tags: ios, iphone, kernel, crash-reports, panic

```
    {“bug_type":"210","timestamp":"2020-04-12 19:33:01.00 +0200","os_version":"iPhone OS 13.4.1 (17E262)","incident_id":"193753D5-4906-4176-89C4-900C53AE9F57"}
{
  "build" : "iPhone OS 13.4.1 (17E262)",
  "product" : "iPhone11,6",
  "kernel" : "Darwin Kernel Version 19.4.0: Mon Feb 24 22:04:54 PST 2020; root:xnu-6153.102.3~1\/RELEASE_ARM64_T8020",
  "incident" : "193753D5-4906-4176-89C4-900C53AE9F57",
  "crashReporterKey" : "e57fa3065c06be4e04642d1160658f6e66de8741",
  "date" : "2020-04-12 19:32:52.92 +0200",
  "panicString" : "panic(cpu 0 caller 0xfffffff02457cbbc): SEP Panic: :sars\/sars: 0x0002d5dd 0x0000aefc 0x0000a95c 0x000233ac 0x000243fc 0x00028aa8 0x0000c24c 0x000261d0 [itltt]\n\nPanic app vers: 1267.100.68.0.1\nPanic app UUID: F0C7ADBD-756B-3C9B-A88F-FE89B84AB2FB\nRoot task tag:  AppleSEPOS-1267.100.68.0.1\nRoot task vers: AppleSEPOS-1267.100.68.0.1\nRoot task UUID: BC6B30F4-37AE-3DC2-8721-691DA72B0835\n\nFirmware type: UNKNOWN SEPOS\nSEP state: 9\nPM state: 2\nBoot state: 32\nMailbox status:\nIDLE_STATUS: 0x00000008\nMAILBOX_SET: 0x00000000\nMAILBOX_CLR: 0x00000000\nINBOX_CTRL: 0x00106701\nOUTBOX_CTRL: 0x00027701\n\nMailbox entries:\nUnavailable\nMailbox queue pointers: 3\/3 0\/0 -1\/-1 -1\/-1 -1\/-1 -1\/-1 -1\/-1 -1\/-1 -1\/-1 14\/14 21\/21 -1\/-1 -1\/-1 -1\/-1 -1\/-1 -1\/-1 0\/0 27\/27 11\/11 18\/18 -1\/-1 -1\/-1 -1\/-1 -1\/-1 -1\/-1 -1\/-1 -1\/-1 -1\/-1 -1\/-1 -1\/-1 -1\/-1 -1\/-1\nDebugger message: panic\nMemory ID: 0xff\nOS version: 17E262\nKernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 19.4.0: Mon Feb 24 22:04:54 PST 2020; root:xnu-6153.102.3~1\/RELEASE_ARM64_T8020\nKernel UUID: 1B052FBE-0096-3353-8DC1-DFC954D4F412\niBoot version: iBoot-5540.102.4\nsecure boot?: YES\nPaniclog version: 13\nKernel slide:     0x000000001bdd4000\nKernel text base: 0xfffffff022dd8000\nmach_absolute_time: 0x237abdcfd\nEpoch Time:        sec       usec\n  Boot    : 0x5e92ec13 0x000ca5b9\n  Sleep   : 0x5e934d5c 0x000332c2\n  Wake    : 0x5e9350a7 0x000f1c73\n  Calendar: 0x5e9350b2 0x00095ecd\n\nPanicked task 0xffffffe0008eb040: 27268 pages, 307 threads: pid 0: kernel_task\nPanicked thread: 0xffffffe002f18548, backtrace: 0xffffffe060b835e0, tid: 10679\n\t\t  lr: 0xfffffff02397c8d8  fp: 0xffffffe060b83620\n\t\t  lr: 0xfffffff02397c71c  fp: 0xffffffe060b83690\n\t\t  lr: 0xfffffff023a9c4b0  fp: 0xffffffe060b836b0\n\t\t  lr: 0xfffffff023a91450  fp: 0xffffffe060b83760\n\t\t  lr: 0xfffffff023f9b7e4  fp: 0xffffffe060b83770\n\t\t  lr: 0xfffffff02397c038  fp: 0xffffffe060b83ae0\n\t\t  lr: 0xfffffff02397c3d8  fp: 0xffffffe060b83b30\n\t\t  lr: 0xfffffff024fa6e94  fp: 0xffffffe060b83b50\n\t\t  lr: 0xfffffff02457cbbc  fp: 0xffffffe060b83b80\n\t\t  lr: 0xfffffff024571778  fp: 0xffffffe060b83ba0\n\t\t  lr: 0xfffffff023f10364  fp: 0xffffffe060b83bd0\n\t\t  lr: 0xfffffff0239beb70  fp: 0xffffffe060b83bf0\n\t\t  lr: 0xfffffff0239be7f8  fp: 0xffffffe060b83c90\n\t\t  lr: 0xfffffff023fa46ac  fp: 0x0000000000000000\n\n",
  "panicFlags" : "0x2",
  "otherString" : "\n** Stackshot Succeeded ** Bytes Traced 368912 **\n",
  "memoryStatus" : {"compressorSize":8767,"compressions":29346,"decompressions":450,"busyBufferCount":0,"pageSize":16384,"memoryPressure":false,"memoryPages":{"active":20673,"throttled":0,"fileBacked":49574,"wired":29492,"purgeable":266,"inactive":6777,"free":85744,"speculative":37368}},
  "processByPid" : {
    "0" : {"pid":0,"residentMemoryBytes":153534464,"timesDidThrottle":0,"systemTimeTask":0,"pageIns":0,"pageFaults":4319,"userTimeTask":2071.0667238750002,"procname":"kernel_task","copyOnWriteFaults":0,"threadById":{"588":{"continuation":[0,18030208],"userTime":6.3749999999999999e-06,"systemTime":0,"id":588,"basePriority":81,"name":"IOAsynchronousScheduler","user_usec":6,"schedPriority":81,"system_usec":0,"state":["TH_WAIT","TH_UNINT"],"waitEvent":[1,6100420143126104991]},"142":{"continuation":[0,18030208],"userTime":0.001472625,"systemTime":0,"id":142,"basePriority":81,"name":"AppleCredentialManager","user_usec":1472,"schedPriority":81,"system_usec":0,"state":["TH_WAIT","TH_UNINT"],"waitEvent":[1,6100420143127014751]},"528":{"continuation":[0,18030208],"userTime":0.089637083000000006,"systemTime":0,"id":528,"basePriority":81,"name":"AppleSPU","user_usec":89637,"schedPriority":81,"system_usec":0,"state":["TH_WAIT","TH_UNINT"],"waitEvent":[1,6100420143126211615]},"112":{"continuation":[0,18030208],"userTime":0.017903333,"systemTime":0,"id":112,"basePriority":81,"name":"AUC","user_usec":17903,"schedPriority":81,"system_usec":0,"state":["TH_WAIT","TH_UNINT"],"waitEvent":[1,6100420143124716511]},"2784":{"continuation":[0,14300052],"userTime":3.3624999999999997e-05,"systemTime":0,"id":2784,"basePriority":81,"name":"ifnet_start_utun0","user_usec":33,"schedPriority":81,"system_usec":0,"state":["TH_WAIT","TH_UNINT"],"waitEvent":[1,6100420143170983143]},"750":{"continuation":[0,18030208],"userTime":2.9160000000000001e-06,"systemTime":0,"id":750,"basePriority":81,"name":"AppleEffaceableBlockDevice","user_usec":2,"schedPriority":81,"system_usec":0,"state":["TH_WAIT","TH_UNINT"],"waitEvent":[1,6100420143125857391]},"589":{"continuation":[0,18030208],"userTime":1.3226387909999999,"systemTime":0,"id":589,"basePriority":81,"name":"IOAsynchronousScheduler","user
```

Can anyone help me to how to read this report in order to understand what caused the crash?